# How to fix a PowerShell script to close automatically on success?

Tags: powershell, android-studio, automation

i created this script text for Android Studio launch configuration:

```bash
(flutter build web) -and (xcopy C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\build\web C:\Web\nginx\data\www\MyApp /E /C /H /R /O /Y)
```

It builds the web version and copies it to the Nginx folder.

How to make Android Studio close the console in case of success, and not close it in case of an error?

Comment: Just tried [stop-process -Id $PID](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48de4962-4300-49c7-a536-6cce93846f76/how-to-close-active-powershell-window-upon-script-completion?forum=winserverpowershell) at the end of a script in the Windows environment and it worked.  But I don't know if it would work in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

- Windows PowerShell:

```bash
flutter build web
if ($0 -eq $LASTEXITCODE) { xcopy C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\build\web C:\Web\nginx\data\www\MyApp /E /C /H /R /O /Y }
if ($0 -eq $LASTEXITCODE) { exit 0 }
pause # An error occurred - keep the window open
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which offers a Bash-like `&&` and `||` operators, called [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators):

```bash
flutter build web && 
  xcopy C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\build\web C:\Web\nginx\data\www\MyApp /E /C /H /R /O /Y &&
  $(exit 0)
pause # An error occurred - keep the window open
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Note: I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but in case it opens an *interactive, stay-open* console to run tasks, you can use `[System.Environment]::Exit(0)` to exit the session *as as whole* rather than just your script.

Comment: Thank you. I modified your script a little for run configuration Android Studio. `flutter build web ; if ($Lastexitcode -eq 0) {xcopy C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\build\web C:\Web\nginx\data\www\myapp /E /C /H /R /O /Y; exit 0;} else {pause; exit 1; };`